# i want to show notification in laravel using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, notifications

issue is this counter will show the notification that how many review has been come. but when i click on it for mark as read the it will not make the value of is_read=  true

```
//controller code
 public function markReviewsAsRead($id)
{
    // Find the review by its ID
    $review = CustomerReview::find($id);

    if ($review) {
        // Update the is_read status to true
        $review->update(['is_read' => true]);

        // Return a response indicating success
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    } else {
        // Return a response indicating failure (review not found)
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Review not found'], 404);
    }
}
```

ajax code

```
$('a[href="{{ route('reviews') }}"]').click(function(event) {
    
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var markAsReadUrl = '/mark-reviews-as-read/' + id;
    $.ajax({
        url: markAsReadUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // Update the notification counter to 0
            $('.notification-counter-reviews').text(0);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('Error marking review as read:', error);
        }
    });

   
});
```

web route

```
Route::post('/mark-reviews-as-read/{id}', [CustomerReviewController::class, 'markReviewsAsRead']);
```

view file code

```
<li>
                    <a href="{{ route('reviews') }}">
                        <span class="notification-counter-reviews">0</span> <!-- Notification counter -->
                        <span class="icon">
                            <ion-icon name="star-outline"></ion-icon>
                        </span>
                        <span class="title">Customer-Reviews</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

i expect this when i click on review anchor then if any review have unread then its is_read become true and flag will reset to 0. does anyone help me ? i am new and i have stuck in this problem few days ago

Comment: where's your id tho??